# How to open app which is available in simulator or device but not in app store through json link in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, url

On my application I have to go from one application to another through json data.
If the app is available on app store then user wont get any issue but if app is not available on app store and if we are trying to call the json then it dosen't open the json url which I am getting through previous app.
Is there any way to open that app which is NOT available on app store but available through build or anything?

Comment: I think the URL scheme is disappear in iOS6, is possible?

Comment: do you have the URLScheme for the App That u want to open.,??

Comment: Cant specify. Now I set the URL scheme for app in my under but what about other app. My issue is solved by using URL scheme

Comment: @nishi then accept any answer if u r getting it.,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can open another application from your Application. but you need know the URlscheme for that Application.,
For Example i want to open an URl with some links, Then i will Use the following to open that URL From my application.,

```
   NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

if you want to know more about the URLScheme Refer the Following  Link.,
It may help you

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18

Answer (score 2):

You can open any app using a custom URL scheme. Ask the app makers to add one and adjust the JSON and launcher accordingly.